# Tomcat 9 JDK 14 "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef"

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have a java web app that has been working normally with Netbeans 12 and Tomcat 9. However, I recently updated my JDK from 1.8.0 to 14.0.2 and now I get this error every time I try to run the project:

```
27-Jul-2020 23:29:47.565 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5121)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1644)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1479)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I've added javax.xml.ws to my pom file with no luck:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also tried without success:

- Using the jakarta version instead of javax in my pom
- Adding the jaxws-api jar to Tomcat's lib folder
- Switching to JDK 9, 10, 11, 13
- Switching to Tomcat 8.5, 10

I can even import/reference the WebServiceRef class in my code without a compile error, so I know it's there. Why am I getting this error/how do I fix it?

I can post more details if needed.

EDIT:

I believe the error is in starting Tomcat and not in running my project. My project is able to build without error - it's only when it's being deployed that I get the error. I've downloaded the source for Tomcat and can indeed see the use of the WebServiceRef class. My thought is that since javax.xml.ws is no longer included in JDK 9+, Tomcat's code is throwing an error. I just don't know how to add the library for Tomcat to use - adding it to the lib folder didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems that question is about a runtime error in their application's code. I may be mistaken, but mine looks like a runtime error in Tomcat's code. I'll update my question more info.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to resolve this by adding the following JARs to Tomcat's lib folder (JAX WS API and all its dependencies):

- jaxws-api-2.3.1
- jaxb-api-2.3.1
- javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0
- javax.annotation-api-1.3.2
- java.activation-api-1.2.0

Comment: Did you mean javaX.activation-api-1.2.0?